# iPhone provisioning issue

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.
I had a free application and decided to add iAd to it. I made the changes in my application and even successfully submitted the application to iTune (waiting for review) and also can debug and see the application just fine on iPhone Simulator but there is a very strange issue here.
When I try to run the application on my device from XCode it keeps telling me I don't have a provisioning profile for this application on my iPhone and I need to install one. I choose "Run and Install" and application is installed on my iPhone but it keeps quitting the application and I get an error on the console saying:

Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1138.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1138.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.

the process id changes between runs.

If I try to run the application again it keeps saying the same error and quitting right after I launch the application.

I can run the application on my iPhone by taping on it and it won't quit but it won't show the ad banner on my pages!

BTW, I can run and debug other applications on my device with no issue!

Again thanks for your help,

Amir

Answer (score 1):

Well I resolved the issue,
As usual it was a silly one, I was trying to run the application under distribution provisioning instead of development!
It's all good now!

I thought this might help others.

Amir

Comment: Ah, can't tell you how often I struggle trying to fix that when all I needed to do was switch it over to the debugging profile. :)